# What would be the ideal base resistor for a 2N3904 running as a switch

Tags: transistors, current, resistors, switches

I'm trying to replace silk screen pads with a board with transistors as switches on it. The power leads leading to the silk screen pads have a limited current of 150μA @ 3.3v. The micro controller I'm using to drive the transistors runs also at 3.3v. What would be the best base resister value?

Here is what im trying to do.[image]

Comment: Without a schematic, you're not going to get a useful answer.

Comment: I just added it as you posted.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you run current through the silk screen on your PCB?  Is that even possible?

Comment: What the heck are silk screen pads?

Comment: Closing as gibberish.  If you really are doing something highly unusual, then you need to explain that.  More likely, you just don't know what you're doing and need to learn some basics.

Comment: The microcontroller is really putting out 1 V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the schematic you have produced is wrong, and the microcontroller outputs are 3.3 volts rather than 1 volt, the base current is nominally $$i_b = \frac{3.3 - 0.7}{R}$$ and$$ R = \frac{2.6}{I_b}$$

If the 2N3904 is to act as a switch, you should assume a gain of about 10, so the base current should be about 15 uA. Then$$ R = \frac{2.6}{15\times 10^{-6}}= 170 \text{ kohm} $$

However, you asked for the "best" value, but you did not define what "best" means. The nominal value ought to work OK. For instance, the microcontroller may not put out exactly 3.3 volts (although with this small a load current it ought to do pretty well), so you might want a slightly smaller, like 150 k, resistor. At these levels you really don't need to worry about "best". Nothing's going to overheat, and you really don't need to worry.

And, although you have not considered it, you should pay attention to the leakage currents through the 2N3904, and ask if they are similar to the load current. As it happens, [the datasheet, page 3](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N3904.pdf) says that the cutoff current is a max of 50 nA, so there are no problems there.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly any resistor will work at such a low load, under 1 mA. Use a 1kΩ or 4.7kΩ resistor and be done with it.

Comment: Actually no transistor will work.  You can't solder them to the silkscreen, and it's insulating anyway if you could.  If you make a guess and change information from what is presented in the question, then you need to state so.  This answer is wrong as it currently stands.  Also, answering bad questions is itself bad.  Those that write really bad questions should be rewarded with their desired result.

Comment: Look I adjusted the question to be more specific.